# How to install virtualenv without admin privilage (Window 7, python 3.5.3)?

Tags: python-3.x, window, pip, virtualenv

I rarely used windows machine for development. Unfortunately... I need to use that this time. This morning, I installed python on a window machine. Unfortunately, I don't have the admin privileges. So, this is what I did:

- Download embedded zip for python 3.5.3 from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.3/python-3.5.3rc1-embed-amd64.zip)
- I extracted it to a folder `C:\python3.5.3` and set the environment variable to PATH
- I installed `pip`
- I also added `C:\python3.5.3\Scripts` to my `PATH` so that I can run pip anywhere.
- I installed the `virtualenv` via `pip`, hence the virtualenv is available on the `C:\python3.5.3\Scripts` directory.

  - `pip install vitualenv`
- I then run the `virtualenv test`. When I run this command, I got this following error:

  ```
  Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\python3.5.3\python.exe
  Using base prefix 'C:\\python3.5.3'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\python3.5.3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>main()
    File "c:\python3.5.3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
  symlink=options.symlink)
    File "c:\python3.5.3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
      site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
    File "c:\python3.5.3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1147, in install_python
      writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
    File "c:\python3.5.3\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 362, in writefile
      with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Luca\\env\\python35.zip\\site.py'
  ```

Is there any workaround related to this issue?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Why even bother if it's the only python you're going to install? Why not use the installer instead? What am I missing here? Sorry for the questions, I never saw the use for virtualenv, as I only use one version anyway and the installer does all that needs to be done all by itself.

Comment: I don't have the admin privilege to installed it with the normal installer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try Python's [builtin venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) - you can create a virtual environment with

```
python3 -m venv foldername
```

You may need to switch `python3` for `python` or even `py` depending on how the Python executable is listed in your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a portable python installation mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201299/2721453).

About the embeddable package(from [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-embeddable)):

> The embedded distribution is a ZIP file containing a minimal Python environment. It is `intended for acting as part of another application, rather than being directly accessed by end-users`.