# VirtualEnv and python-embed

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, embed

I have a Windows machine running many apps using Python 2. I want to add a new program I wrote using Python 3. To make sure I don't screw anything up, I wanted to use a Virtualenv with Python 3 embedded ([Python 3 embed amd64](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/python-3.6.4rc1-embed-amd64.zip)).

So I extracted the embedded python 3 and tried running virualenv with the --python option enabled.

I tried running the virtualenv

```
    python -m virtualenv --python E:\Projects\python3-embed\python.exe E:\Projects\Virtual\
```

And I got this error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter E:\Projects\python3-embed\python.exe
Using base prefix 'E:\\Projects\\python3-embed'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1147, in install_python
    writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 362, in writefile
    with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\Projects\\Virtual\\python36.zip\\site.py'
```

I am not entirely sure how can I fix this error. There is a site.pyd file in python36.zip but it seems that virtualenv can't use it.

Answer (score 12):

### Sorry in advance

I **knew** this is not the answer you meant to ask for, but I tried hard that ***(our)*** way, and got this solution at last.

---

### TL;DR

> #### Update on 17 December 2021
>
> The download page has been moved to https://winpython.github.io/
> , for my purpose, I will download Winpython64-3.10.0.1dot.exe for now. Please don't forget to verify the checksum for the executable package.
>
> End of the update on 17 December 2021

Use the [**portable installer with postfix "Zero"**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/WinPython_3.7/3.7.0.2/) from [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/)

- WinPython64-3.7.0.2Zero.exe(64 bit version, **YOU want this**)
- WinPython32-3.7.0.2Zero.exe(32 bit version)

---

### The *Too Long* version

#### What I tried

- Yes, I downloaded the **python-3.7.0-embed-amd64.zip** from [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/)
- Yes, I set it up according to instructions in [this page](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/python-install-python-with-pip-on-windows-by-the-embeddable-zip-file/)
- Yes, it worked as a python interpreter

  ```
    D:\temp\test>python
    Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    >>>
  ```
- Yes, I installed the package **virtualenv**

  ```
    D:\temp\test>virtualenv --version
    16.0.0
  ```
- Then, boom **(where you asked)**

  ```
    D:\temp\test>virtualenv ENV
    Using base prefix 'd:\\portable\\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    File "D:\portable\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
    File "D:\portable\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 712, in main
        symlink=options.symlink)
    File "D:\portable\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 927, in create_environment
        site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
    File "D:\portable\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1149, in install_python
        writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
    File "D:\portable\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 363, in writefile
        with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\temp\\test\\ENV\\python37.zip\\site.py'
  ```

  Seems a problem with `virtualenv`, searched, got [an open issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/422), and I don't like that long solution.

  This is the **end of virtualenv**.
- Then, I tried `venv`:

  ```
    D:\temp\test>python -m venv venv
    D:\portable\python-3.7.0-embed-amd64\python.exe: No module named venv
  ```

  Yes, the **"built-in module"** was lost, and the [document for Embedded Distribution](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution) doesn't even mention it, just something about **Tcl/tk (...), pip and the Python documentation are not included**.

  This is the **end of venv**.

#### Well, start again from my original point

The purpose to choose **Embedded Distribution** is (just like *SOMEBODY*):

> To make sure I don't screw anything up

1. this include "**don't install** anything into my *unstable and oversized Windows*"
2. but doesn't necessarily "**must use** the *Official Embedded Distribution*"
3. something **portable and trusted** is enough, yes [**Portable Python**](http://portablepython.com/)
4. but the main page says "Portable Python is not being developed anymore", and provide some choice
5. after some reading, I figured out, what I want is [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/), the version with a *Zero*
6. ta-da ... **That's it**.

#### Something about Embedded Distribution (from [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#windows-embeddable))

> The embedded distribution is a ZIP file containing a minimal Python environment. It is `intended for acting as part of another application`, rather than being directly accessed by end-users.

Comment: 2 years later that saved me considerable ammount of time, since I am in the middle of your process and now I can skip the second half and just proceed to the actual solution. This should be popular knowledge by now.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded distribution is meant to be lightweight.  To install a virtual environment, follow these steps.

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Once these steps are done, proceed with the recommended approach and create a virtual environment using the command below.  The --system-site-packages is typically used to bring a non embedded distribution packages already in the python install into the virtual environment, but since this is embedded, you can omit.  But it won't hurt to have it.

```
python -m venv --system-site-packages C:\Python\python-3.7.9-embed-amd64\py37venv
```